# Scala: a tricky case involving anonymous subclasses, callbacks, and type parameters

Tags: scala

I'm not even sure how to describe what I'm doing, except with an example:

```
class Node

abstract class App {
    def schema: Node
}

def bind(app: App, f: Node => Node) {
    f(app.schema)
}

val app = new App {
    val schema = new Node {
        val child = new Node
    }
}

bind(app, _.child)
```

This does not compile. I get:  `error: value child is not a member of this.Node` from the `bind` call.

I'm not sure how to fix this, but I think it probably involves use of parameterized types. I need the type of `f`'s parameter to be that of the actual `Node` subclass assigned to `schema`.

**EDIT:** I can not explicitly name my `Node` subtypes, as in real life I have entire trees of statically defined `Node`s and it would not be practical to name them.

Answer (score 4):

`Ǹode` has no method `child` so  class App must retain the parameter of the enclosed node:

```
abstract class App[N <: Node] {
  def schema: N
}
```

Then you can extend `Node` to include child:

```
class ParentNode extends Node {
  def child = new ParentNode
}
```

Finally you can write `bind` as:

```
 def bind[N <: Node](app: App[N], f: N => N) = {
    f(app.schema)
 }

 val app = new App[ParentNode] {
    val schema = new ParentNode
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @paradigmatic. I should clarify that I need to maintain the use of the anonymous Node subtype. This is representative of an internal DSL I am developing, and it's important that the Node trees be easy to implement and not require explicit naming of subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
def bind[T](app: App{val schema: T}, f: T => Node) { f(app.schema) }
bind[{val child: Node}](app, _.child)
```

I imagine that is still too verbose for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, but that would require repeating the entire schema inside the parameter type definition. In real life the schema is a large graph of connected Node instances.

Answer (score 2):

`bind` has signature `App x (Node => Node) => Node`

`_.child` in this context means `{n: Node => n.child}` and Node does not define child. Which is what your error message tells.

In your particular case, you could expect it to work, because you know the function argument of bind is applied to the schema Node of the app argument. However, you should tell nearly as much to the compiler. And that will force you to make some of the implementation details more public.

First, maybe your function will not have a Node argument, but something more precise. You could have that has a generic parameter :

```
def bind[N <: Node](app: App, f: N => Node)
```

But then when you call `f(app.schema)` then you must make sure that app.schema has the required type

```
class App[N <: Node] {def schema: N}
def bind[N <: Node](app: App[N], f: N => Node) = f(app.schema)
```

Last you will have to make the type of your app val more explicit, at least

```
class NodeOfApp{def child: Node}
val app = new App[NodeOfApp]{...}
```

Comment: Thank you. See my comment to @paradigmatic. I can not explicitly name my Node subtypes, as in real life I have entire trees of statically define Nodes and it would not be practical to name them.